# Maven - generate an RPM and Jar using a single POM file

Tags: java, maven, jar, maven-2, rpm

I am working on Maven RPM Plugin and I have my directory structure as below

```
  dir1
  dir2
  dir3
  src
  pom.xml
```

dir1,dir2,dir3 directories contain my custom files and the src directory has my Java source code.

I want to create the Jar file by building the Java application and then bundle everything to an RPM(dir1,dir2,dir3,src, jar file generated). I have tried the below

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

  <groupId>xyz</groupId>
  <artifactId>abc</artifactId>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <packaging>jar</packaging>

  <name>xyz</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>

  <properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <build.number>1</build.number>
        <maven.rpm.plugin.version>2.0.1</maven.rpm.plugin.version>
  </properties>
<profiles>
    <profile>
            <id>rpm</id>
            <activation>
                <activeByDefault>true</activeByDefault>
            </activation>
            <build>
                <plugins>
                    <plugin>
                        <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
                        <artifactId>rpm-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                        <version>${maven.rpm.plugin.version}</version>
                        <executions>
                            <execution>
                                   <id>generate-rpm</id>
                                    <goals>
                                         <goal>rpm</goal>
                                </goals>
                            </execution>
                        </executions>
                        <configuration>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                            <copyright>XYZ</copyright>
                            <release>${build.number}</release>
                            <group>DOC/COD</group>
                            <mappings>
                                <mapping>
                                <directory>/tmp</directory>
                                </mapping>
                            </mappings>
                        </configuration>
                    </plugin>
                </plugins>
            </build>
        </profile>
    </profiles>
  <dependencies>

    <dependency>
  <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
  <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
  <version>1.1</version>
</dependency>

    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>3.8.1</version>
      <scope>test</scope>
    </dependency>
  </dependencies>

  <repositories>

</repositories>
</project>
```

The target directory is being created with the JAR file of the Java source code but the RPM is not getting created. It throws the below error

```
  Failed to execute goal org.codehaus.mojo:rpm-maven-plugin:2.0.1:rpm (generate-rpm) on   project xyz: RPM query for default vendor returned: '127' executing '/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'' -> [Help 1]
```

Please let me know if I am in the right direction and how to proceed on this.

Comment: That sounds like you don't have the `rpm` binary on your system. What kind of system is this? Can you run `rpm` from a shell manually?

Comment: @EtanReisner: I have tried in Centos where RPM packages were installed.

Comment: Can you run `/bin/sh -c rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}'` as whatever user maven is running as (or running that as) and see what you get?

Comment: it gives this and the usage details      `RPM version 4.8.0
Copyright (C) 1998-2002 - Red Hat, Inc.
This program may be freely redistributed under the terms of the GNU GPL`

Comment: That is not at all the correct output for that command. Something is very wrong. That should give you something like `redhat` as output. What does `type rpm` say? Can you post the usage information that command spit out? Also what does `rpm -E '%{_host_vendor}' &>/dev/null; echo $?` output?

Comment: Type RPM give `rpm is /bin/rpm`   usage Information  `Usage: rpm [-aKfgpWHqVcdilsKiv?] [-a|--all] [-f|--file] [-g|--group] [-p|--package] [-W|--ftswalk] [--pkgid] [--hdrid] [--fileid] [--specfile] [--triggeredby] [--whatrequires]
        [--whatprovides] [--nomanifest] [-c|--configfiles] [-d|--docfiles] [--dump] [-l|--list] [--queryformat=QUERYFORMAT] [-s|--state] [--nofiledigest] [--nomd5] [--nofiles] [--nodeps]
        [--noscript] [--comfollow] [--logical] [--nochdir] [--nostat] [--physical] [--seedot] [--xdev] [--whiteout] [--addsign] [-K|--checksig] [--delsign] [--import] [--resign]
   `

Comment: That looks like the correct start to the usage. Do you get `redhat` if you run `rpm -E %{_host_vendor}` manually? I'm betting you do. I get your version/usage output if I run `/bin/sh -c rpm -E %{_host_vendor}` too. But that's a quoting problem. The command needs to be `/bin/sh -c 'rpm -E %{_host_vendor}'` to pass the whole string to `/bin/sh`. The maven plugin is getting the quoting wrong somehow.

Comment: yes I get **redhat** when I execute the `rpm -E %{_host_vendor}`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/59286/discussion-between-charles-babbage-and-etan-reisner).

Answer (score 0):

Maven works best when conventions are followed, and when they are, very little configuration is needed. That being said, the convention of Maven is **one** artifact per module (and of course on `pom.xml` per module).

Therefore, the best way to structure your project would be like the following:

```
ProjectName
|
|--ChildJarModule
|  |
|  |--pom.xml
|
|--ChildRPMModule
|  |
|  |--pom.xml
|
|--pom.xml
```

If you do this, you'll have an easier time generating your RPM from the pom.xml in the ChildRPMModule (and you may very well solve your problem).

Comment: Thanks @Hypino. As per my requirement I want my directory structure as specified above.could you validate my POM file ?